# How I can move part of text in MS Word with VBA to right side?

Tags: string, vba, ms-word

I need to write macro thats splits string into two parts. One part of text goes to left allign in word, second to right.

I found in this topic manual steps for doing it, my question is how to do it automatically?

https://superuser.com/questions/484261/word-formatting-need-to-align-left-to-left-right-to-right-in-same-line

I tried to make two text columns in Word:

```
With ActiveDocument.PageSetup.TextColumns 
 .SetCount NumColumns:=2 
End With
```

but I don't know how to put my parts of text into desired column. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Constuntine help I found solution - in every line that I want to split to left and right side I do following action:

```
With objWord
        .Visible = False
        .Selection.TypeParagraph
        .Selection.TypeText ("ABC" & vbTab & "123")
        .Selection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add Position:=CentimetersToPoints(17), _
        Alignment:=wdAlignTabRight, Leader:=wdTabLeaderSpaces
End With
```

Comment: I tried with your answer/help above, but it "CentimetersToPoints" sub not defined error is coming. Please provide its defintion if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the developer tab and clicking 'Record Macro'. Then do the splitting manually. After that click 'Stop Recording'. This will give you the commands needed to automatically split the text.